# Rounded intersection Android Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

I'm new to Android canvas. I'm cutting Canvas using `.ClipPath(path)`. in the `path` I used `lineTo()` method to add all the lines. now I need to the rounded corners of all corners like Pic-2. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: Using Bezier Curves: similar to this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073682/how-to-draw-bezier-curve-in-android

Comment: @emandt bro! how can I get the other points of Bezier Curves?